# How to return a Swift enum for handling error conditions

Tags: swift, syntax, error-handling, enums

I'm trying to create a simple error handling structure in Swift. What I'd like to do is return a type that includes either a 'Success' code, or, an 'Error' code. But to make it a little tricky, in the error case, I also want to get a message and a diagnostic string.

I came up with this, which compiles fine and works just great as far as returning the success/error:

```
enum PasswordValidationResult {
    case Success
    case PasswordError(message: String, diagnostic: String)

    func isValid() -> Bool {
        switch self {
        case .Success:
            return true
        case .PasswordError:
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

And I can return the desired value(s):

```
return PasswordValidationResult.PasswordError(message: "You can't do that", diagnostic: "XYZ")
```

The problem comes when I try to reference the return value.

Clearly, I can use the isValid() function to test for the success condition, but I can't find any syntax for referencing the message and diagnostic strings.

For instance, trying this:

```
  myError = someFunction()

  if myError == PasswordValidationResult.Error {
    // None of this will compile, at all...
    println(myError.message)
  }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can extract the associated values of an enum using `switch`:

```
switch someFunction() {
case .Success:
    println("It worked!")
case .PasswordError(let message, let diag):
    println(message)
}
```

Amongst other nice things `switch` does, if your cases exhaust all possibilities (as here – the enum must be one of the two values) you don’t need a default.  And if you forget and miss one, the compiler will warn you.

Note, you can also match specific values:

```
switch someFunction() {
case .Success:
    println("It worked!")
case .PasswordError("Password invalid", _):
    println("Please try again")
case let .PasswordError(message, diag):
    // more general error handling
}
```

Comment: So, giving the parts of the `PasswordError` tuple names in the declaration is pointless.

Comment: @nhgrif not sure what you mean

Comment: `case PasswordError(message: String, diagnostic: String)` <-- from the code snippet in the question.  Naming the parts of this tuple is pointless, right?

Comment: Oh I see. Well, with two strings, it serves the purpose of documenting which is which, I guess. Otherwise you’d have to look at the docs to know the first is the message and second the diag.

Comment: Yeah, but you'd probably be better off with some different sort of tuple probably...

Answer (score 2):

Another, slightly more convenient way to access those values is to add computed properties to your `enum` for each associated value:

```
enum PasswordValidationResult {
    // ...

    var errorMessage: String? {
        switch self {
        case let .PasswordError(message, _):
            return message
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }

    var errorDiagnostic: String? {
        switch self {
        case let .PasswordError(_, diagnostic):
            return diagnostic
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Those properties will be `nil` for a success, and give you easy access to the values you want when the result is an error.

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the associated value as a tuple with element names using `switch`:

```
let myError = someFunction()

switch myError {
case .Success:
    println("success")
case .PasswordError(let err):
    println("message: \(err.message)")
    println("diagnostic: \(err.diagnostic)")
}
```

Comment: Also a good tip... didn't know you could grab the whole tuple like that.